# Trouble with arrays in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I need an array to be created with a PHP loop.

It will look like:

```
[ utcdate1:[ series1:[value], series2:[value], series3:[value], utcdate2:[ series1:[value], series2:[value], series3:[value], etc..... ]
```

Here is my code:

```
totals = { <?php
    for ($i=0; $i < count($date); $i++) {
        echo "Date.UTC(".
             $year[$i].",".
             $month[$i].",".
             $day[$i].
             "):[ Movies:[".$nomovies[$i].
             "], Shows:[".$noshows[$i].
             "], Music:[".$nomusic[$i].
             "] ]";
        if ($i < (count($date)-1)) {
            echo ",";
        }
    } ?> };
```

Why doesn't this code work?

Comment: Is this Java? PHP? I'm confused. Can you clarify the question -- a **lot**?

Comment: For one you need to format your code on multiple lines, this is impossible to follow.  Secondly, I would suggest you setup the array in PHP and then just use json_encode to convert it into javascript..

Comment: @timramich: Ah, I see, it's JavaScript not Java. You do understand that these are two completely different programming languages, that they are about as similar as ham is to hamster, right?

Comment: The problem I'm having is with the Date.UTC.  It's taking it as a literal string and not doing anything with the data in the parentesis.  That json_encode stuff is too complicated for me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compute JS property name on the fly. Try this:

```
totals = {};
<?php
for ($i=0; $i < count($date); $i++) {
    echo "totals[Date.UTC(".
         $year[$i].",".
         $month[$i].",".
         $day[$i].
         ")] = [ Movies:[".$nomovies[$i].
         "], Shows:[".$noshows[$i].
         "], Music:[".$nomusic[$i].
         "] ];";
} ?>
```

EDIT:
While we're at it, **JavaScript is not Java**.  JavaScript runs in browsers and is the future of HTML5.  Java commonly runs on server, as programs, or as applet, and is now a static type traditional programming language.  They are quite different, really, both in syntax and in concept.

So, tag wisly next time.

Comment: thanks much, yours worked.  Thank you everyone else, too.  And now I know Java is not the same thing as javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not support associative arrays (hashes), so you can't convert this to an array. Also you're very confused, you are not trying to make a JavaScript array, it's obvious you are trying to make a JSON object.

You can do it like this:

This is the first approach:

```
totals = {
    <?php
        for ( $i = 0; $i < count($date); $i++ )
        {
            $tempDate = new DateTime("{$year[$i]}-{$month[$i]}-{$day[$i]}");
            echo $tempDate->getTimestamp() . ": {"
                . "Movies: [{$nomovies[$i]}],"
                . "Shows: [{$noshows[$i]}],"
                . "Music: [{$nomusic[$i]}],"
            // Add trailing comma, until last element in array is reeached.
            if ( $i < count($date)-1 )
            {
                echo ",";
            }
        }
        // Close the object.
        echo . "}";
    ?>
};
```

Here is a second:

```
<?php
    // Init an empty array.
    $someArray = array();
    // Fill the array up with the correct structure and all.
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($date); $i++ )
    {
        // Init a date object with the desired time.
        $tempDate = new DateTime("{$year[$i]}-{$month[$i]}-{$day[$i]}");
        // Convert the time to seconds and use as a hash in the array.
        $someArray[ $tempDate->getTimestamp() ] = array(
            "Movies" => array( $nomovies[$i] ),
            "Shows" => array( $noshows[$i] ),
            "Music" => array( $nomusic[$i] ),
        );
    }
    // Encode that bad boy into a JSON object.
    echo "totals = " . json_encode( $someArray ) . ";";

?>
```

I updated my answer, I think this is what you really want. This way the date gets converted to seconds since the epoch date, and will be safe to use as a property/key in a JSON object.

Comment: I'm wondering whether the question is confusing JSON and normal JS object, actually, espcially since timramich knows the date part is giving him trouble.

Comment: He's trying to use the date as a property in the JSON, which I've never tested, but I don't think that will work. The problem is we don't know what he wants to end up with.